# Change default behavior of the translation function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, translation, multilingual

For debugging purpose, I would like that whenever I call `__('non-existing-key')`, to see printed for example `STRING NOT FOUND`, so that I can crawl my website and search for that specific string...

Are there ways to do it?

Comment: The key must be exactly "non-existing-key" or it represents any not found translation? I wrote my answer but now I don't know if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two files in **app/Extended** (the folder must be created if doesn't exist):

ExtendedTranslationServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Extended;

use Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider;

class ExtendedTranslationServiceProvider extends TranslationServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerLoader();
        $this->app->singleton('translator', function ($app) {
            $loader = $app['translation.loader'];
            $locale = $app['config']['app.locale'];
            $trans = new ExtendedTranslator($loader, $locale);
            $trans->setFallback($app['config']['app.fallback_locale']);
            return $trans;
        });
    }
}
```

ExtendedTranslator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Extended;

use Illuminate\Translation\Translator;

class ExtendedTranslator extends Translator
{
    public function get($key, array $replace = [], $locale = null, $fallback = true)
    {
        $trans = parent::get($key, $replace, $locale, $fallback);
        if(parent::get($key, [], $locale, $fallback) === $key){
          return 'STRING NOT FOUND';
        }
        return $trans;
    }
}
```

And add a new item in the `providers` array, on app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Extended\ExtendedTranslationServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Comment: damn, i'll try ti asap

Comment: but i still should use the `__()` function ? shouldn't i do something like binding this provider to some interface in the boot method?......

Comment: Yes, you should use as the same way as before, but, when there's a not found translation (`if(empty($trans))` line), the string "STRING NOT FOUND" will return.

Comment: Somehow is not working... i'm using 6.x, maybe this was meant for some other version?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure, it was tested on 7.x, try to add on the first line of the function `get` something like `echo 123; die` and see if the "123" appears. About the expected behavior, is that correct? It should show "STRING NOT FOUND" to any not found translation, right?

Comment: I think it's because laravel returns the string key if not found, and so it's never "empty(..)"

Comment: infact in the default translator i can see in the "has" method `$this->get($key, [], $locale, $fallback) !== $key`

Comment: yup, using `if(parent::get($key, [], $locale, $fallback) === $key)` works fine

Comment: Yes Lucius, with the edit that i've pointed out it works fine, update the question and i'll mark as correct and give you a +1

Comment: Works fine for me.. but i override get in another way. Thanks